# Spring web application, Injection of autowired dependencies fail

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am setting up a simple Hello World web application with Spring and Maven.
Somehow, I keep getting a BeanCreationException when trying to autowire my test bean.

Hello Bean:

```
package de.dijon.test;

public class HelloBean {
private String name;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getHello() {
    return ("Hello " + name);
}
}
```

web.xml:

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

application-context.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="helloBean" class="de.dijon.test.HelloBean"
    autowire="byType">
    <property name="name" value="Dijon" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

My test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:/application-context.xml" })
public class AppTest extends TestCase {

@Autowired
private HelloBean obj;

@Test
public void test() {
    assertNotNull(obj.getHello());
}
}
```

Errormessage:

```
Dec 23, 2013 1:31:59 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@2b275d39: startup date [Mon Dec 23 13:31:59 CET 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 23, 2013 1:31:59 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@371bed71] to prepare test instance [null(de.dijon.test.test.AppTest)]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'de.dijon.test.test.AppTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private de.dijon.test.HelloBean de.dijon.test.test.AppTest.obj; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [de.dijon.test.HelloBean] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:384)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:326)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private de.dijon.test.HelloBean de.dijon.test.test.AppTest.obj; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [de.dijon.test.HelloBean] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [de.dijon.test.HelloBean] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 28 more
Dec 23, 2013 1:31:59 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@2b275d39: startup date [Mon Dec 23 13:31:59 CET 2013]; root of context hierarchy
```

Maybe somebody could help me, and tell me, what the reason for not properly auto wiring is. I tried to find this out for the last couple of hours and don't have any ideas.
Thank you very much!

Comment: XML configuration is (essentially) deprecated. Use `context:component-scan` and annotations.

Comment: where is your application-context.xml located? In WEB-INF/ or in src/main/resources/ ?

Comment: My application-context is in /WEB-INF/

Comment: If it is in WEB-INF, then @ContextConfiguration shouldn't find it. Are you sure you don't have another applicationContext.xml somewhere? Please read this page, another guy had the same problem as you. http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/49585-how-to-get-contextconfiguration-using-web-inf-applicationcontext-xml

Answer (score 1):

You have to Annotate your `HelloBean` with one of the available stereotype.

***Explanation of stereotypes :***

- `@Service` - Annotate all your service classes with `@Service`. All your
  business logic will be in Service classes.
- `@Repository` - Annotate all your DAO classes with `@Repository`. All
  your database access logic should be in DAO classes.
- `@Component` - Annotate your other components (for example REST
  resource classes) with component stereotype.
- `@Autowired` - Let Spring auto-wire other beans into your classes using
  `@Autowired` annotation.

***Difference***

`@Component` – Indicates a auto scan component.
`@Repository` – Indicates DAO component in the persistence layer.
`@Service` – Indicates a Service component in the business layer.
`@Controller` – Indicates a controller component in the presentation layer.

***Reasons to use them*** :

- The main advantage of using `@Repository` or `@Service` over
  `@Component` is that it's easy to write an AOP pointcut that targets,
  for instance, all classes annotated with `@Repository`.
- You don't have to write bean definitions in context xml file. Instead
  annotate classes and use those by autowiring.
- Specialized annotations help to clearly demarcate application layers
  (in a standard 3 tiers application).

Also

```
<context:component-scan base-package="de.dijon.test"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I changed my code, now, but I still get the same Exception. I annotated the HelloBean as Component/Service and added the context tag to my application context. Perhaps I am missing some dependencies? Which modules do I need? I use: spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web and spring-test.

Comment: You need spring-webmvc-(version).release.jar in your class path Download latest version

Comment: Added webmvc module. But it doesn't change anything :(

Answer (score 0):

In your test, change the name of the property from obj to helloBean

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven in your project you should store the configuration file in the classpath according the maven project structure

> src/test/resources/application-context.xml

then change your `@ContextConfiguration` annotation to

```
@ContextConfiguration("/application-context.xml")
```

and run the test again.

Your configuration file can not be resolved because `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` folder is not in the classpath by default, the configuration file is a file system file or a project file so you should reference it as is

```
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/application-context.xml")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
<context:component-scan base-package="de.dijon.test.*"
        annotation-config="true" use-default-filters="true" />
```

in application-context.xml file

Comment: This didn't work either. I annotated the HelloBean, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Remove <bean id="helloBean" class="de.dijon.test.HelloBean"
    autowire="byType">
    <property name="name" value="Dijon" />
</bean> and try